# How to write the below sql query using $this->db

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
SELECT Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Shippers
ON Orders.ShipperID=Shippers.ShipperID
GROUP BY ShipperName;
```

Comment: By Going through this: http://www.php.net/pdo.query

Comment: active records https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$this->db->select('Shippers.ShipperName,COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders');
$this->db->join('Shippers', 'Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('ShipperName');
$getResult=$this->db->get('ShipperName');
```

Comment: Please post the table structure and your model & controller code

Comment: I am checking to provide you the working code...Meanwhile Can you please edit your question and add the table structure for both the tables

Comment: Your posted question and code are different. Your question contains Shippers and order table while model & controller code contains sales & people. I suggest you to post either correct code or screenshot

Comment: This is too much confusing for me atleast...can you please upload your project on github so that I can download and check what issue exactly is because after above discussions requirement is ambiguous for me

Comment: sry.Here I need the explanation for sales&people only..This is my model code

Comment: $this->db->select('COUNT(customer_id) AS customer_count');
  $this->db->from('sales'); 
  $this->db->join('people', 'sales.customer_id = people.person_id','left');
  $this->db->group_by("people.first_name");

Comment: The problem is that if i use "left" here iam getting the "undefined property error for 'customer count'" otherwise it is working fine but the result is not accurate...please give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db
    ->select('b.ShipperName, count(a.OrderID) as NumberOfOrders')
    ->join('Shippers b', 'b.ShipperID = a.ShipperID', 'left')
    ->group_by('b.ShipperName')
    ->get('Orders a')->result_array();
```

Comment: Here is my code:$this->db->select('COUNT(ospos_sales.customer_id) AS customer_count');
$this->db->from('sales'); 
$this->db->join('people', 'sales.customer_id = people.person_id','left');
  $this->db->group_by("people.first_name");

Comment: Here iam passing the customer_count to the $person->no_bills=$CI->Person->get_info_no_bills($person->person_id)->customer_count; in table_helper.php file...when i try to excute iam getting 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$customer_count

Filename: helpers/table_helper.php

Line Number: 59

Comment: please can any one help in this...many thanks in advance..if I remove the "left" its excuting but iam not getting the accurate result...

Comment: Can you post your full code of `get_info_no_bills` method on your model? Note that when calling object/stdclass property values are achieved by assigning it first, else you will get an `undefined property` error: `$row = $this->db->get()->row(); $this->customer_count = $row->customer_count`.